# Python manage.py runserver is throwing error after Ubuntu upgrade to 20.0

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, pip

I am getting this error in all the Django projects on my system. I've updated from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.0 (Focal Fossa). Since then I am getting these errors.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 10, in main
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
  File "/home/thebitshoes/Desktop/Environments/namllpV1_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from django.utils.version import get_version
  File "/home/thebitshoes/Desktop/Environments/namllpV1_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/version.py", line 6, in <module>
    from distutils.version import LooseVersion
  File "/home/thebitshoes/Desktop/Environments/namllpV1_env/lib/python3.6/distutils/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    real_distutils = imp.load_module("_virtualenv_distutils", None, distutils_path, ('', '', imp.PKG_DIRECTORY))
  File "/home/thebitshoes/Desktop/Environments/namllpV1_env/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 245, in load_module
    return load_package(name, filename)
  File "/home/thebitshoes/Desktop/Environments/namllpV1_env/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 217, in load_package
    return _load(spec)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 683, in _load
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name'
```

Comment: You typically need to create new virtual enviornments and reinstall your modules into them after upgrading python.

Comment: Thanks !!  I actually went in the virtual environment folder and in the terminal I issued the command to create the virtual env instead of creating a new one .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it as per followiing the comment by **jordanm**, Thanks a lot for pointing me to this direction

I issued the command to create the virtual env instead of creating a new one in the folder where the environment was residing.

This produced the following :

```
 virtualenv -p python3 namllpV1_env

Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/bin/python3
Using base prefix '/usr'
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv.py:1041: DeprecationWarning: the imp module is deprecated in favour of importlib; see the module's documentation for alternative uses
  import imp
New python executable in /home/thebitshoes/Desktop/Environments/namllpV1_env/bin/python3
Not overwriting existing python script /home/thebitshoes/Desktop/Environments/namllpV1_env/bin/python (you must use /home/thebitshoes/Desktop/Environments/namllpV1_env/bin/python3)
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
```

Then when I did python manage.py it showed some different errors like Django not found etc.

So I uninstalled Django and reinstalled it again followed by other packages that I am using.

Now it's working !!

Comment: Yup. Virtual environments hardcode some paths, so if you may get errors if you move the folder to another locations also.